# ¿Como puedo guardar un archivo PDF a una BD en SQL con C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

soy nuevo en esto y necesito guardar un pdf dentro de una base de datos con C# hecha con VS 2015.

Cita en bloque

Comment: Saludos, ve a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio. Preguntas así son apaleadas con negativos porque carece de intentos de resolver el problema, nada de código y sólo un enunciado. También son potencialmente cerradas. Edita la pregunta, agrega los detalles que tienes, el código que hiciste y la parte que te genera problemas, bienvenido/a a SOes.

Comment: Te recomiedo que no guardes archivos en la BD. Lo mejor es simplemente guardar direcciones hacia un servidor de archivos que los contenga.

Comment: Como dice Luis es mejor guardar el archivo como un archivo y en sql guardar solo la referencia, pero ese archivo va ligado con algun otro dato digamos algun documento de usuario, primero revisa el comentario de @fredyfx

Comment: Si necesitas persistir el archivo como parte de la db investiga el `FileStream` de Sql server, este hay que configurarlo pero permite definir un container asociado a la db donde persistir los documentos

Answer (score 0):

convertilo a un arreglo de byte no podes guardar un PDF en una base de datos.

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("archivo.pdf");
```

despues cuando quieras abrirlo lo haces asi:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("archivo.pdf", bytes);
```

Comment: pero en esa respuest falta como persistir el dato en la db, solo le indica como leer el archivo y recuperar los bytes array

Comment: Guardas el arreglo de bytes

Comment: pero justamente lo que pregunta es como lo guarda, es lo que no respondes

Comment: analiza el link a la pregunta que menciono como duplicada para ver a lo que hago referencia